# What caulk to use for basement floor control joint?

Tags: concrete, caulking, caulk

My basement floor has control joints and some have opened up. Floor was poured 5 years ago and the cracks are stable now.

The worst section is 3/16ths wide.

What caulk should I use to seal this? I want something safe for indoor use.

[image]

Comment: What is your purpose in wanting to caulk it?

Comment: Primary purpose is to seal any soil gas coming up from imperfect vapor barrier install below the slab. We have a radon mitigation system as well. I have no idea how accurately that vapor barrier is fit…

Comment: I would use polyurethane caulk.  either the DAP or SILKA products,  the waterproof one...

Answer (score 2):

I've used this stuff in many a basement or garage.  It is designed to bond to the concrete, the color blends into undyed concrete, and it can be applied with a caulking gun (much easier than the squeezy tubes for doing long cracks).

You don't really have to worry about Radon infiltration if you already have a mitigation system, even if the vapor barrier isn't perfectly sealed.  It's not under pressure or anything so that system of sub-slab pipes and vent stack already provides a path of least resistance for the gas to bypass you and escape to atmosphere.  In high-Radon areas like where I used to live, builders install a fan to pull a slight vacuum as well.

[image]

Note: this is not a specific product recommendation FWIW.  Quite a few brands produce this type of sealer.